# Is there a way to check if a user input in c++ is in a certain predefined vector and if not tell the user to re-enter the input?

Tags: c++

Right now I'm making a text-based game on c++ and one problem I'm facing is ensuring that user input is valid.  I can do this easily with numbers but for `<char>` I'm having issues.  Essentially the user should only input either "F", "S", "H" or "Q" and in python I'd do that as

```
acceptable_chars = ["f", "s", "h", "q"]
inp = input("Please enter a command.")
while inp.lower() not in acceptable_chars:
    inp = input("Please enter a valid input: ")
```

I'm fairly new to c++ and to my knowledge there is no function that checks if something is n something.  Would there be a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: `while (std::find(std::begin(acceptable_chars), std::end(acceptable_chars), inp) == std::end(acceptable_chars))`

Comment: If you use std::vector have a look here: https://www.techiedelight.com/check-vector-contains-given-element-cpp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, single characters and strings have different types. For single characters, use single quotes: `'f'`, `'h'`, etc. For strings, use double quotes: `"f"`, `"h"`, `"quit"`, etc.

I assume you want to use single characters; if you want to use strings, replace `char` by `std::string` in the code below.

To organize your valid choices, you can use `std::set`:

```
#include <set>
...
int main()
{
    std::set<char> acceptable_chars{'f', 's', 'h', 'q'};
    ...
}
```

To check whether a `char` is inside your set, you can use `count`:

```
...
int main()
{
    std::set<char> acceptable_chars{'f', 's', 'h', 'q'};
    char inp;
    do {
        inp = input("Please enter a command.")
    } while (acceptable_chars.count(inp) == 0);
}
```

Comment: What's really the difference between a vector and a set.  You mentioned organise my valid choices, so if you wouldn't mind what's the difference betwwen a set and a vector.

Comment: The purpose of `vector` is holding items which you can reorder. In a `set`, you usually ignore the order - the implementation orders your items in whatever fashion it wants. As a result, search in a `set` is faster than in a vector. In C++ Standard Library, efficient operations have dedicated methods, so you have this `count` method, which looks cleaner than using `find` in a `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::find`, e.g.

```
std::vector acceptable_chars = {'f', 's', 'h', 'q'};
char inp;
std::cin >> inp;
while (std::find(std::begin(acceptable_chars), std::end(acceptable_chars), inp) == std::end(acceptable_chars))
    std::cin >> input;
```

I used `std::vector` because you asked about vector. I prefer `std::unorderd_set` with `std::unordered_set::find` or `std::unordered_set::contains` (C++20)

```
std::unordered_set acceptable_chars = {'f', 's', 'h', 'q'};
char inp;
std::cin >> inp;
while (acceptable_chars.find(inp) == std::end(acceptable_chars)) {
// while (acceptable_chars.contains(inp)) { /* C++20 */
    std::cin >> inp;
}
```

`std::find` on a vector has a time complexity of *O(n)*. `std::find` will stop after the first hit. `std::count` on a vector has a time complexity of *O(n)* but it will search the whole container even though it found a hit at the beginning.

`std::unordered_set` is a hashmap. `std::unordered_set::find`, `std::unordered_set::count` and `std::unordered_set::contains` have a time complexity of *O(1)* on average.

It won't make any measurable difference for your example but it's good to know about the different containers and methods.

Comment: do i need to include anything because right now std::unordered_set gives me "undeclared idemtifier"

Comment: @JustinChee Yes, you need the header `unordered_set`. Read more https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set

Answer (score 1):

For a very short command list like in your example (`{'f','s','h','q'}`), I would argue it's easier to type out each case:

```
void input()
{
  char c;
  cout << "Please enter a command.\n";
  while (cin >> c && c != 'f' && c != 's' && c != 'h' && c != 'q')
    cout << "Please enter a valid input: ";

  cout << "you entered command: " << c << endl;
}
```

If the command list grows, then it becomes tedious to type all the cases. Perhaps the neatest syntax for this is with the C++20 ranges library:

```
vector cmds {
  'h','j','k','l',
  'i','a','o','y',
//...
};

void input()
{
  char c;
  cout << "Please enter a command.\n";
  while (cin >> c && !ranges::contains(cmds, c))
    cout << "Please enter a valid input: ";

  cout << "you entered command: " << c << endl;
}
```